# batch file doesnt read powershell edited text file correctly

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a powershell script that writes to a text file

```
$text = "Primary" |Out-File \\DS-01A\WINRedundancy\FailoverStatus.txt
```

[image: Text File]

and a batch file that reads in the contents of the text file into a variable.

```
set /p FAILOVR_STS = <FailoverStatus.txt
```

The problem is that the batch file does not read the text file correctly. It looks like some conversion is happening after being edited by the shell script as evident in the batch output. It reads B instead of Backup

[image: Batch Output]

Not sure what is going on. If i create a new text file and edit it, the batch file reads it correctly.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't powershell default to Unicode when creating a text file.  I believe you need to tell it to use ascii when creating the FailOverStatus.txt file.

Comment: great point..will try that and let you know

Comment: Example 3: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: @ Squashman That worked. Thank you very much .In the powershell script set encoding to ascii   $text = "Primary" |Out-File \\EMS-DS-01A\WINRedundancy\FailoverStatus.txt -Encoding ascii

Comment: Side Note: The `$text = ` portion of your powershell is pointless. You explicitly output to a file, so there is nothing to be captured with the `$text` variable.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `Out-File` you need to encode it `ascii`

```
'Primary' | Out-File \\DS-01A\WINRedundancy\FailoverStatus.txt -Encoding ascii
```

*Removed `$text` because it is unecessary*

> From `Get-Help Out-File -Online` (Microsoft Cmdlet Documentation)
>
> ```
> -Encoding
> Specifies the type of character encoding used in the file.
> Unicode is the default.
> ```